# How can I import a variable from another JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to import an array (`imageArray[]`) that is being populated by another JavaScript file (`imageUploadDisplay.js`) into another JavaScript file function (`postInfoAndImages.js`). Below is my `imageUploadDisplay.js` function that I tried to use.

```
// In my imageUploadDisplay.js

var imageList = [];

function myImageList() {

    return imageList;
}
```

As explained by others I use the following jQuery to import `imageUploadDisplay.js` into the JavaScript `postInfoAndImages.js`:

```
// In my postInfoAndImages.js
var imageList = [];

$.getScript('imageUploadDisplay.js', function () {
            // Script is now loaded and executed.
            alert("Script loaded, but not necessarily executed.");
            imageList = myImageList(); // Picture array
            console(imageList);
        });
```

Comment: You define the same variable in two files?

Comment: Yes was attempting to at least copy the values from 1 array to the other

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having.

Comment: I want to access the array created and populated by `imageUploadDisplay.js` into a function created in `postInfoAndImages.js`

Comment: You are *not* importing anything into `postInfoAndImages.js`, contrary to what you are thinking. You are simply executing a piece of code which is injecting another script to the document itself, and **not** to `postInfoAndImages.js`, thus it should already be globally accessed, depending on what's inside the injected script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to include the second file in your first to use the function. If the first file is called in your code before the second, you can just refer to the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="imageUploadDisplay.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="postInfoAndImages.js"/>
```

In postInfoAndImages.js, simply call the function in question:

```
var imageList[];
imageList = myImageList();
```

Comment: logically that makes sense but I got a' UncaughtReferenceError: myImageList is undefined'

Comment: It should work if you have it referenced properly. I did a quick test.

In my first js I have:

var cars = ["Saab", "Acura", "Volvo"];

function myCarList() {
  return cars;
}

A console.log(myCarsList()) returns the above array.

In my second file I called it again but with a blank array and I get the blank array returned.

cars = myCarList();
console.log(cars);

Answer (score 6):

For modern browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, just use ES6 modules.

In your `imageUploadDisplay.js` create a named `export`:

```js
// imageUploadDisplay.js
var imageList = [];

export function myImageList() {
  return imageList;
}
```

Then just import the function:

```js
// then in postInfoAndImages.js
import { myImageList } from './path/to/imageList.js';

var imageList = myImageList();
```

In your HTML, you no longer need to include `imageUploadDisplay.js` (this is done by the import at runtime).

Instead, include the importing script with `type="module"`:

```
<script type="module" src="./path/to/postInfoAndImages.js"></script>
```

Comment: I got an 'Uncaught SyntexError: Unexpected token

Comment: That happens if you forget `type="module"`.

Comment: Okay the error is gone but there's no feedback on my `console.log(imageList)` and my function doesn't execute past it

Comment: What do you mean *there's no feedback on my `console.log(imageList)` and my function doesn't execute past it*?

Comment: I've put the initial `imageList[]` in my `imageUploadDisplay.js` in a console log and it shows me the number of files in it so now that I've imported it in `postInfoAndImages.js` the  `imageList[]` doesn't show anything when put it in the console log

Comment: Does imageUploadDisplay.js do anything asynchronous?

Answer (score 3):

You need to work with [exports and imports](https://javascript.info/import-export).

```
// File imageUploadDisplay.js

let myImageList = () => {
    return imageList;
}

export default imageList
```

And then import it into the other file

```
// postInfoAndImages.js

import imageList from "./imageUploadDisplay"

// -> Do something with imageList
```